# Why the statement of saving the function reference to a variable is necessary?

Tags: javascript

Recently I've been reading the You Don't Know JS book series on Github, one snippet of code really eludes me. I simplified the code and present you the two different versions of code below:

The correct version:

```js
var fun = function () {
  console.log("this is something");
}

var func = fun; // why this line?

fun = function() {
  func.call(null);
}
fun();
```

The wrong version:

```js
var fun = function () {
  console.log("this is something");
}

fun = function() {
  fun.call(null); // why this causes error?
}
fun();
```

If you run snippet two, the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" would occur.
I can not understand why the line `var func = fun;` in snippet one is necessary.

Comment: You avoid overriding reference, hence you avoid the recursive call to `fun`. In snippet 2, the last `fun` you are calling is, in fact, the last defined reference for it. The first one is not referenced by anyone anymore.

Comment: Ever heard of recursivity? You call the function inside itself until the call stack overflows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fun = function() {
  fun.call(null);
}
fun();
```

You have a function that calls whatever is stored in `fun`, and you assign it to `fun`. That's just infinite recursion.

The rest of the code doesn't matter. In particular, the old value of `fun` is never used before the assignment `fun = ...` overwrites is.

What's different in the first example is that `func` is never overwritten, so it still keeps a reference to the first function, the one that just calls `console.log`.

In other words, in the first case the chain of calls goes

```
fun --> func --> console.log
```

with `fun = function () { func.call(null) }` and `func = function () { console.log("this is something") }`,

whereas in the second case it goes

```
fun --> fun --> fun --> fun --> ...
```

with `fun = function () { fun.call(null) }`.

---

What's crucial here is that `function() { fun.call(null); }` does not capture a copy of `fun`. It's not like the value of `fun` is frozen in place at the time the function is defined, so to speak.

Instead the function captures the variable itself (not the value it had at some point). That's why when the function is called, it uses whatever value is stored in `fun` at the time of the call.

A simplified demonstration of the issue:

```js
var x = "hello";

var f = function () {
    console.log(x);
};

x = "bye";
f();
```

This code prints `bye`, not `hello`.

Comment: Why `var func = fun;` prevents the infinite call then?

Comment: @HaoZonggang I've added a longer explanation. Hopefully some of it makes sense.